# Explain me about auto-resize issue in different iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am facing issue in auto resize in iPhone app development with `CGRectMake`. Can anyone explain about it?

```
CGRect imgframe=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 283);
UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgframe];
 KMAppDelegate *app=(KMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 [imgview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:app.imgString];
```

Comment: fix your aspect ratio

Comment: Paste your code or question will be closed.

Comment: use aspect ratio feature..

Comment: why issue r u facing ?

Comment: if i run in 3.5retina dan its working perfect but in retina4.0 its not working the way i want because of size

Comment: you need to set **imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;** to make it flexible, I had same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try this code..it may help you..

```
    imgview =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 283)];
    KMAppDelegate *app=(KMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 [imgview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:app.imgString];
    imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

enjoy coding..

Answer (score 0):

```
  CGRect imgframe=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 283);
    UIImageView *imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imgframe];
    KMAppDelegate *app=(KMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [imgview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:app.imgString];
    imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [[self view] addSubview:imgview] ;
```